# Applying OSX tags based on filename with hazel

Tags: shell, tags, workflow

I was wondering if anybody had seen a script that would allow hazel to automatically apply a tag by observing a filename. For e.g. If a file was named `xyz #Research #Uni` then it would apply the tags `Research` and `Uni` to the file (and ideally remove the `#Research` `#Uni` from the filename once it had applied the tags leaving the filename as `xyz`)?